# Is it possible to manually cancel and retrigger a Svelte animation?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have an animation that depends on the value of a writable store.

For example:

```
{#if $isWorking}
    <span in:fade="{{duration: 200, delay: 750}}">Working...</span>
{/if}
```

The problem is that if the value of the store changes fast enough the transition won't restart. [Here's is a REPL that demonstrates this behavior.](https://svelte.dev/repl/8f78dc32a03547ff8e402520b51fbd76?version=3.24.0)

I imagine this is because Svelte is very efficient. My guess is that if the value of `$isWorking` is the same at the start of the following frame, Svelte will decide it hasn't changed and will keep the transition going.

This seems like a fine default behavior, but is there a way to avoid this and reset the animation manually? In this case, to restart the delay whenever the `$isWorking` store changes?

I've come up with a hack to avoid using the `delay` property of the transition and implementing myself it using `setTimeout`:

```
let show = false;
let timeout;

isWorking.subscribe((value) => {
    show = false;
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        showState = true;
    }, 750);
});

{#if show}
    <span in:fade="{{duration: 200}}">Working</span>
{/if}
```

Is there a more Svelty way to solve this?

Comment: I made a little test, where I toggle the ’show’-variable with a timeout. At a second round of off/on-toggling, the animation fails if the timeout is the same as the delay in animation. See REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/b2ec0d970ac1408397131b6d0faa9375?version=3.24.0

Comment: Do note that when using the timeout the animation does not have a delay.

Comment: Can you provide a REPL? Just interested to see the implementation of the portion "the value of the store changes fast enough".

Comment: @CarlosRoso https://svelte.dev/repl/8f78dc32a03547ff8e402520b51fbd76?version=3.24.0

Comment: With "on:keyup" animation works as intented: https://svelte.dev/repl/c3da4842771142e09ac269c804c1e23c?version=3.24.0

Comment: Would `tick` work for you? https://svelte.dev/repl/5386bba20b3d478f84f034b2da3e7efe?version=3.24.0. Svelte gathers all intros and outros and waits until the next frame to update the view. If your state is changing in the same microtask then it will go unnoticed to Svelte. You can use https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick to force Svelte to update the view in this case. I can post it as an answer if you find it useful.

Comment: @CarlosRoso yes, thanks! Please write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tick` for this.

```
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { tick } from 'svelte';
    let show = false;
    
    async function onInput () {
        show = false;
        await tick();
        show = true;
    }
</script>

<input on:input={onInput}>

{#if show}
    <span in:fade="{{duration: 200, delay: 500}}">working...</span>
{/if}
```

Svelte gathers all intros and outros and waits until the next frame to update the view in batch. If your state is changing in the same microtask then it will go unnoticed to Svelte. You can use [tick](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick) to force Svelte to update the view in this case.